# How can I un-export a variable, without losing its value?

Tags: environment-variables

Let's say I exported a variable:

```
foo=bar
export foo
```

Now, I'd like to un-export it. That's to say, if I do `sh -c 'echo "$foo"'` I shouldn't get `bar`. `foo` shouldn't show up in `sh -c`'s environment at all.
`sh -c` is merely an example, an easy way to show the presence of a variable. The command could be anything - it may be something whose behaviour is affected simply by the presence of the variable in its environment.

I can:

1. `unset` the variable, and lose it
2. Remove it using `env` for each command: `env -u foo sh -c 'echo "$foo"'`

   - impractical if you want to continue using the current shell for a while.

Ideally, I'd want to keep the value of the variable, but not have it show up at all in a child process, not even as an empty variable.

I guess I could do:

```
otherfoo="$foo"; unset foo; foo="$otherfoo"; unset otherfoo
```

This risks stomping over `otherfoo`, if it already exists.

Is that the only way? Are there any standard ways?

Comment: You could echo the value into a temporary file, using `mktemp` if *that* is portable enough, and unset the value, and source the temporary file to assign the variable.  At least a temporary file can be created with a more or less arbitrary name in contrast to a shell variable.

Comment: @Sukminder The `sh -c` command is merely an example. Take any command within which you cannot unset a variable in its stead, if you will.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no standard way.

You can avoid using a temporary variable by using a function. The following function takes care to keep unset variables unset and empty variables empty. It does not however support features found in some shells such as read-only or typed variables.

```sh
unexport () {
  while [ "$#" -ne 0 ]; do
    eval "set -- \"\${$1}\" \"\${$1+set}\" \"\$@\""
    if [ -n "$2" ]; then
      unset "$3"
      eval "$3=\$1"
    fi
    shift; shift; shift
  done
}
unexport foo bar
```

In ksh, bash and zsh, you can unexport a variable with `typeset +x foo`. This preserves special properties such as types, so it's preferable to use it. I think that all shells that have a `typeset` builtin have `typeset +x`.

```sh
case $(LC_ALL=C type typeset 2>&1) in
  typeset\ *\ builtin) unexport () { typeset +x -- "$@"; };;
  *) unexport () { … };; # code above
esac
```

Comment: For those unfamiliar with [`${var+foo}`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_an_alternate_value), it evaluates to `foo` if `var` is set, even if empty, and nothing otherwise.

Comment: Say, do you have any comments on `typeset +x` vs `export -n` for the shells that do support the former? Is `export -n` rarer, or does it not preserve some properties?

Comment: @muru If you're writing a bash script, you can use `export -n` or `typeset +x` indifferently. In ksh or zsh, there's only `typeset +x`.

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT:** For `bash` only, as pointed out in the comments:

The `-n` option to `export` removes the `export` property from each given name.  (See `help export`.)

So *for `bash`,* the command you want is: `export -n foo`

Comment: That's shell-specific (see [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#export)), OP did not specify a shell, but asked for a *standard* way of solving the problem.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, wasn't aware of that.  Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a similar POSIX function, but this doesn't risk arbitrary code execution:

```sh
unexport()
    while case ${1##[0-9]*} in                   ### rule out leading numerics
          (*[!_[:alnum:]]*|"")                   ### filter out bad|empty names
          set "" ${1+"bad name: '$1'"}           ### prep bad name error
          return ${2+${1:?"$2"}}                 ### fail w/ above err or return 
          esac
    do    eval  set '"$'"{$1+$1}"'" "$'"$1"'" "$'@\" ###  $1 = (  $1+ ? $1 : "" )
          eval  "${1:+unset $1;$1=\$2;} shift 3"     ### $$1 = ( $1:+ ? $2 : -- )
    done
```

It will also handle as many arguments as you care to provide it. If an argument is a valid name that is not otherwise already set it is silently ignored. If an argument is a bad name it writes to stderr and halts as appropriate, though any valid name preceding an invalid on its command-line will still be processed.

I thought of another way. I like it a lot better.

```sh
unexport()
        while   unset OPTARG; OPTIND=1           ### always work w/ $1
                case  ${1##[0-9]*}    in         ### same old same old
                (*[!_[:alnum:]]*|"")             ### goodname && $# > 0 || break
                    ${1+"getopts"} : "$1"        ### $# ? getopts : ":"
                    return                       ### getopts errored or ":" didnt
                esac
        do      eval   getopts :s: '"$1" -"${'"$1+s}-\$$1\""
                eval   unset  "$1;  ${OPTARG+$1=\${OPTARG}#-}"
                shift
        done
```

Well, both of these use a lot of the same techniques. Basically if a shell var is unset a reference to it will not expand with a `+` parameter expansion. But if it is set - regardless of its value - a parameter expansion like: *`${parameter+word}`* will expand to *`word`* - and not to the variable's value. And so shell variables self-test and self-substitute on success.

They can also *self-fail*. In the top function if a bad name is found I move `$1` into `$2` and leave `$1` null because the next thing I do is either `return` success if all args have been processed and the loop is at an end, or, if the arg was invalid, the shell will expand the `$2` into `$1:?` which will kill a scripted shell and return an interrupt to an interactive one while writing *`word`* to stderr.

In the second one `getopts` does the assignments. And it won't assign a bad name - rather write it will write out a standard error message to stderr. What's more it saves the arg's value in `$OPTARG` *if* the argument was the name of a set variable in the first place. So after doing `getopts` all that is needed is to `eval` a set `OPTARG`'s expansion into the appropriate assignment.

Comment: One of these days, I'll be in the psychiatric ward somewhere after trying to wrap my head around one of your answers. :D How does the other answer suffer from arbitrary code execution? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @muru - `fn(){ eval "set -- \"\${$1}\" \"\${$1+set}\" \"\$@\""; }; fn 'x}"; echo kill my computer;return'`

Comment: But doesn't that require *me* to pass a weird variable name (though I suppose user error is possible)? Is there anyway that the contents of the variable, which could be arbitrary, be executed?

Comment: @muru - not unless an argument is an invalid name. but that's not the problem - the problem is that input is not validated. yes, it is required that you pass it an argument with a weird name to make it execute arbitrary code - but that's pretty much the basis for every CVE in history. if you try to `export` a weird name, it won't kill your computer.

Comment: @muru - oh, and the arguments can be arbitrary: `var=something; varname=var; export "$varname"` is perfectly  valid. the same goes for `unset`, and with this and with the other, but the minute the contents of that `"$varname"` variable get crazy, it could be regrettable. and that's pretty how that whole `bash` function export debacle happened anyway.

Comment: @mikeserv i think you'd get a lot more upvotes (at least from me) if you replaced that obfuscated code with code that explains itself (or commented the lines, at least)

Comment: @PSkocik - done.